# Redis not starting on Ubuntu Server

Tags: redis, ubuntu-14.04, digital-ocean

I followed this tutorial and installed `Redis` server

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-redis

It got installed properly my installation setting are like this

```
Selected config:
Port           : 6379
Config file    : redis
Log file       : /var/log/redis_6379.log
Data dir       : /var/lib/redis/6379
Executable     : /usr/local/bin/redis-server
Cli Executable : /usr/local/bin/redis-cli
```

After this I was asked a question like this

```
Is this ok? Then press ENTER to go on or Ctrl-C to abort.
Copied /tmp/6379.conf => /etc/init.d/redis_6379
Installing service...
 Adding system startup for /etc/init.d/redis_6379 ...
   /etc/rc0.d/K20redis_6379 -> ../init.d/redis_6379
   /etc/rc1.d/K20redis_6379 -> ../init.d/redis_6379
   /etc/rc6.d/K20redis_6379 -> ../init.d/redis_6379
   /etc/rc2.d/S20redis_6379 -> ../init.d/redis_6379
   /etc/rc3.d/S20redis_6379 -> ../init.d/redis_6379
   /etc/rc4.d/S20redis_6379 -> ../init.d/redis_6379
   /etc/rc5.d/S20redis_6379 -> ../init.d/redis_6379
Success!
Starting Redis server...
Installation successful!
```

After this I powered it off by running following command

```
sudo service redis_6379 stop
```

after that now when ever I am trying to start the `Redis-Server`

```
sudo service redis_6379 start
```

it is throwing error

```
Starting Redis server...
15465:C 15 Mar 03:03:00.315 # Fatal error, can't open config file 'redis'
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for your redis.conf file with `locate redis.conf`.
If you don't have locate, just `sudo apt install mlocate` and you will be able to locate the redis file.
I have mine in /etc/redis/redis.conf

It should look like this:

http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/redis.conf

Comment: can you be more specific please